# excel database import error in brightway2

Tags: brightway

[screenshot of an exchange causing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Mep.png)I'm desperately attempting to import my Excel spreadsheet into my project in Brightway2, but I first encountered an error due to unique unlinked exchanges. This issue stems from having multiple product activities. To address this, I added a "reference product" column to differentiate my activities, which are meant to be linked to the ecoinvent 3.9.1 cutoff database. Then, I adjusted my importing strategies by adding reference product as follows:

```
imp = bw.ExcelImporter("my_database")
imp.apply_strategies()
imp.match_database("ecoinvent 3.9.1 cutoff", fields=('name','unit','location', 'reference product'))
#imp.match_database(fields=('name', 'unit', 'location', 'reference product'))
imp.statistics()
```

What am I overlooking here? Do I also need to specify a reference product for those activities that have no relation to ecoinvent? such as biosphere, and to those that I created?

Below, you can find the complete type error message:

```
Cell In[193], line 5
      3 imp.match_database("ecoinvent 3.9.1 cutoff", fields=('name','unit','location', 'reference product'))
      4 #imp.match_database(fields=('name', 'unit', 'location', 'reference product'))
----> 5 imp.statistics()

File ~/opt/.../base_lci.py:69, in LCIImporter.statistics(self, print_stats)
     67         for exc in (e for e in ds.get("exchanges", []) if not e.get("input")):
     68             unique_unlinked[exc.get("type")].add(activity_hash(exc))
---> 69     unique_unlinked = sorted(
     70         [(k, len(v)) for k, v in list(unique_unlinked.items())]
     71     )
     73     print(
     74         (
     75             u"{} datasets\n{} exchanges\n{} unlinked exchanges\n  "
   (...)
     82         ).format(num_datasets, num_exchanges, num_unlinked)
     83     )
     84 return num_datasets, num_exchanges, num_unlinked

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I tried various import strategies to handle this issue. But I couldn't import my database.

Comment: can you add an example the exchanges that are unlinked (a screenshot of the excel would do)

Comment: Hi Nabla,

Thank you for your answer. I've just uploaded the screenshot. The issue arises with the exchange for lithium carbonate production, specifically from the spodumene source. This is problematic because there is another exchange with the same activity name but a different product in ecoinvent database. To resolve this, I've added a reference product column to my database and filled it for those exchanges that need to be matched and sourced from the ecoinvent database.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'`. I suspect is because you are using as matching field "reference product" which is only defined for some activities (so it is a None for the case reference product field and a string in other cases).